# displayMenu() - function is not defined error

Tags: python, function, menu

The menu provides input options to the user. The main focus is on having the functions being called without error as previously experienced. The resolution was that my code was incorrectly formatted. displayed() first then login() and register().

Resolution:

```
def displayMenu():
        global menu_input

        menu_input = input("Please enter one of the following options:\n r - register user\n a - add task\n va- view all tasks\n vm - view my tasks\n e - exit\n")

        if menu_input == "r": 
                register()
        elif menu_input == "a": 
                add_task()
        elif menu_input == "va": 
                view_all()
        elif menu_input == "vm": 
                view_more()
        elif menu_input == "e": 
                exit()

        return menu_input
displayMenu()

def login():
        username = input("Please enter your username?:\n")
        password = input("Please enter your password?:\n")

        for line in open("user.txt","r").readlines():
                field = line.strip().split(",")
                if username == field[0] and password == field[1]:
                        print("Username & Password Correct!\n")
                        return True
        print("Username & Password Incorrect\n")
        return False
login() 

def register():
        register = False

        while register == False:
              username = input("Please enter a username?: ")
              password = input("Please enter a password?: ")
              password_check = input("Please re-enter the password?:")
              if password == password_check:
                        file = open("user.txt","a")
                        file.write (username)
                        file.write (",")
                        file.write (password)
                        file.write("\n")
                        file.close()
                        register = True
                        print ("Your login details have been saved. ")

        else:
                        print("Passwords doesn't match!")

register()
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: ***"displayMenu() - function is not defined error"***: Can't reproduce this, please make sure, code you posts actually behaves as you claim.

Comment: @Gabip The error related to displayMenu()

Comment: @b1ack_char1ie ***"What are you getting?"***: It works for me as expected. No error.

Comment: HI Stofl, for me only the Login() function but once I receive the menu and provide input I get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution for me was moving my function login() below all my other functions without calling them unless in the displayMenu() & displayMenu_Admin().

Also, I had to read up on functions() as I didn't understand the concept fully.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the `register` function before you call to the `displayMenu()`.

Try to move you function declarations to the top of your code.

Comment: You should organise better your code (declare all your functions first and then organise all your func calls in one place, in `main` func for example). Your code structure causes a dependencies spaghetti. And avoid using global variables, you don't need them.
Regarding your issue, why not to call `displayManu` from `login` function?

Comment: @b1ack_char1ie anyway your issue is solved. If you have other issues, consider opening a new SO question...